# Flutter layout restriction

Tags: flutter, dart, responsive-design, widget, flutter-layout

Suppose I want to achieve something like this in flutter how can i do this?

[image]

note: first digit(8) should be exactly aligned below first letter of above word (v of vacation) and similarly last digit(6) should be exactly aligned below last letter of above word (n of vacation).

So far i am trying to do it like this and have been unsuccessful.

```
Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        const Text("Vacation"),
        SizedBox(height: 10),
        Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: const [
            Text("8"),
            Text("16"),
          ],
        )
      ],
    );
```

Comment: are the numbers going to be changing? ie 16 becomes a single digit number? I would just use expanded or just set the padding around the Text() to position it where you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your column with `IntrinsicWidth` and remove `mainAxisSize` from `Row`.

Comment: thanks a lot. can you please explain a bit what  magic IntrinsicWidth is doing here ?

Comment: It grants it's child the maximum width the child needs instead of infinity. For example here row can be expanded to infinity but text has a Intrinsic width so it will apply text's width on row. [IntrinsicWidth](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicWidth-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can set each Text inside a Expanded Widget, Expanded makes each object to take as much space as it can in order to spread

[Expanded Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html)

```
Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: const [
        Expanded( child: Text("8"),),
        Expanded( child: Text("16"),),
      ],
    )
```

Hope that works

Comment: No, that doesn't work. I just want the digits to spread enough as much as the length of above word, not more than that

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).